# Regex to remove xx. from the start of a string but only 2 digits (code half completed)

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to work out a quick and simple way to remove the first two digits and a decimal 
from a string, if that is how it is made up.

I am half way there but need help to finish.

So (first is what I start with, 2nd is the result):

```
xx.yyy       =     yyy
aaaaa        =     aaaaa
test.hello   =     test.hello
a.test.b.x   =     a.test.b.x
aa.bb.cc     =     bb.cc
```

So it only removes 2 digits and a decimal if it exists like that. If it is three digits and a decimal then it isn't removed.

This is where I am so far:

```
$string = 'xx.hello';
$pattern = '/(2-digits)./i';
$replacement = ''; // remove if matched
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

?>
```

Comment: `xx` are not 2 digits. They are two characters. Please be clear about your requirement, and give examples to match your text.

Comment: Consider http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: Consider http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do letters, digits, and underscores:

```
preg_replace('/^\w{2}\./', '', $string);
```

Without numbers or underscores, both upper and lowercase:

```
preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z]{2}\./', '', $string);
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Only thing is I need it to be the first two digits. In fact this exactly would fail one of the examples in my question (unless add a 1 as the 4th parameter), but I think it's just a case of changing the first part of the Regex from '/ to '/^ - doing this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "digits" you mean actual digits (0-9) and by "decimal" a dot:

`$string = preg_replace('/^\d{2}\./','',$string);`

Comment: How will this change xx.yyy to yyy?

Comment: @PHPglue OP specifically mentions *digits*. I assumed (and mentioned that in my answer) that `xx` is his way of representing "any two digits".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$pattern = "~^[0-9A-Za-z]{2}\\.~";
```

It matches two alphanumerical characters at the beginning of the string, followed by a period (.). Notice that the period has been escaped so the period is interpreted as a literal. (Otherwise, the period matches any single character.)

Comment: That's a good practice if you are reusing the regular expression in JavaScript, which I do. Otherwise, it is not necessary to use 2 backslashes.

Comment: @PHPglue But it is tidier, in my opinion.